# ASCII underline escape code for Linux terminal capabilities

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, console, ascii

In a Linux terminal emulator with xterm capabilities, printing the escape code `\x1b[4m` will make the following characters print with an underline.

In the Linux console with linux term capabilities, printing the escape code `\x1b[4m` causes the following characters to be printed in blue.

**How do I print underlined text in a Linux console?**

When I mention "linux" or "xterm" term capabilities I'm talking about the output of `$echo $TERM`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `\x1b[4m`, try `$(tput smul)`

```
printf "%s\n" "$(tput smul)This is underlined"
```

Comment: It still prints blue text.

Comment: Can you paste the output of `infocmp linux` ?